# Programming style: Should you check for null in functions or out of functions?

Tags: language-agnostic

When you call a function with a object, should you check for null in the function, before calling the function or both? What is better programming practice?

Something like this

```
Test a = getTest();

if (a != null) {
    myFunc(a);
}

def myFunc(x):
    print x.val();
```

or

```
Test a = new Test();

myFunc(a);

def myFunc(x):
    if (x != null) {
        print x.val();
    }
```

or

```
Test a = new Test();

if (a != null) {
    myFunc(a);
}

def myFunc(x):
    if (x != null) {
        print x.val();
    }
```

I can see why putting the null check in the function is good, because then you don't have to check everywhere, but sometimes u need to check before calling the function, so then it feels redundant to check twice...

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: If you want to blend into the ecosystem, do what your standard library functions do. Does `printf` check for null format string? Does `strcpy` check for null source or destination? Does `fwrite` check for null file pointer or buffer? If they do, you should do that too.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the intended use and/or distribution of the code. This is really based on opinions but I agree with Uncle Bob's opinion on "Defensive programming". If it's a library for your use or your team's use, you should avoid defensive programming, after all you trust your coworkers to not pass null into a function right?

If however you're writing a public API which may be used by *anyone*, you should make the proper checks, especially where passing null could cause a crash.

> Defensive programming, in non-public APIs, is a smell, and a symptom,
>   of teams that don't do TDD.

@unclebobmartin

Comment: asserts can help too.